# Youtube API v3 category topics

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Hey guys I'm not having an issue with the API directly, but with the documentation. I can make an API request and get the video topic details just fine, but I am looking for a master list of all topics.

[According to the documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos) the old style of topics that you can see [here](https://gist.github.com/stpe/2951130dfc8f1d0d1a2ad736bef3b703) was depreciated in 2017 and replaced with Wikipedia articles. This is fine and a little better for my use case but I would like to get a list of all options. The documentation says

> A list of Wikipedia URLs that provide a high-level description of the video's content.

which is not *especially* helpful haha. I think I found [the Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_music_genres_and_styles) Source for all music genres, and it looks like they are just using the "main" genres but I would like to confirm that. I also found [this list of topics](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/categories) that looks similar but is from the natural language API documentation instead of the YouTube API documentation.

I could try and brute force it but that would require a considerable amount of effort with no real way to confirm my results. I also found [this API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list) but it just returns the top level categories.

I am also really only interested in the music categories.

Comment: Interesting. I'm not sure if there is a list of topics available - since that feature is deprecated, can you elaborate about why you're using (*or trying to use*) this feature?

Comment: @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes I am working on a project that is using the YouTube API and since that data is provided with the API I think it would be neat to keep track of that. And also technically the feature is not disabled, there is just an older version that *is*